# php || ubuntu about -- (PID)

Tags: php, ubuntu, ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04

Is there any way to manually set the pid when executing the command line ??

If not, is there a way to learn the pid for the last process?

i tried pgrep $name but it gives more than one pid

-------update---------
what i am trying to do is

```
 $command =  'ffmpeg -reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -
 reconnect_delay_max 2000 -i '.$streamurl.' -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 
 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -f flv '.$rtmp.'' . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!; ';
```

this how i am tring to get the id and it will work only for the first command

```
$command_get_pid =  'pgrep ffmpeg';
$procid = shell_exec($command_get_pid);
```

now if i exec the command one more time the pgrep ffmpeg will return 2 (pid)

Comment: You cant set the pid, but you can [get the pid](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30370/how-to-get-the-pid-of-the-last-executed-command-in-shell-script) of last executed process, or you can find a pid of a running process `ps -ef | awk '/process with arguments/{print $2}'`, need to see how your calling it.

Comment: Can you show the code your trying this with, it may help get answers.

Comment: ya check the update in the up :)

Comment: Whats being returned when you run `$command`?

Comment: you need to quote your `-i` and $rtmp params, build the output echo it and then test it on the cmdline, once its good $! should return a pid.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone nothing !

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thx dude .... its working now :)